# React native build not working in release mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, firebase, react-native

I'm working on my project using React native. When I do the project in debug mode, the app works well on **both simulator and real device**.

**However**, it doesn't work in release mode (I change the release mode in Xcode edit scheme), both simulator and real device. The odd thing is that it **doesnt show any errors at all**. It stucks on the native launching screen (**Not** the splash screen). As far as I know, it does not even run the code inside index.js file.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Looking forward to having your answers.

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "PodRecycling",
  "version": "1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "8081": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && yarn start",
    "splash": "yarn react-native generate-bootsplash splash/ic_koi_fish.png \\--background-color=FFFFFF \\ --logo-width=300 \\--assets-path=assets \\--flavor=main",
    "clean-android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
    "clean-ios": "cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd ..",
    "android": "yarn clean-android && npx react-native run-android ",
    "ios": "yarn clean-ios && npx react-native run-ios",
    "android-release": "clean-android && npx react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "start": "npx react-native start --reset-cache",
    "format": "prettier --write **/*.{ts,tsx,js,json,md}",
    "check-code": "prettier --check **/*.{ts,tsx,js,json,md}",
    "test": "jest",
    "li": "dot_clean -n . && node generateAssetResource.ts",
    "lint": "eslint index.js src --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "pod": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
    "reverse": "adb reverse tcp:9090 tcp:9090; adb reverse tcp:19001 tcp:19001;",
    "cp_all": "yarn cpi && yarn cpa",
    "rlink": "npx react-native link",
    "assembleRelease": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^5.12.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "^0.0.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "npm": "^6.14.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-fast-compare": "^3.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-camera-hooks": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-manager": "^6.5.4-1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^6.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "5.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.2",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "whatwg-url": "^11.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.51",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/whatwg-url": "^8.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.26.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "hjson": "^3.2.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1, macos 11.6.2 (BigSur). Tested app on ios 15.0 and 13.0

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: None taken, I found a solution for my case. If someone also has a custom plugin, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72364266/4465464